# Не срабатывает .submit() после e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не пойму, почему не отправляются данные формы при помощи submit(), после e.preventDefault();

```js
$('#reg-form form input[name="submit"]').on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#reg-form form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reg-form" class="reg-form">
    <div class="exit-reg-form">X</div>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label><div class="errorReg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" title=" ">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#reg-form form')[0].submit();
```

Comment: Попробовал, консоль пишет "TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function"

Comment: @Gagablik `console.log($('#reg-form form').length, $('#reg-form form')[0]);` - ??

Comment: Увидел в логе, что выбрана нужна форма, но не пойму почему не отправляются данные у формы(((

Comment: @Gagablik что в консоли?